# How do I change directory (cd) with Ganymed SSH API?

Tags: java, session, ssh, cd

I must be missing something here, but how do I call something like "cd /root/some/dir/" with Ganymed SSH API?

1. I created a `Connection` object
2. In the first session created, I called "cd /root/some/dir"
3. In the second session created, I  called "ls ."  or "./myApp"

That didnt work, because ganymed probably starts each session with its own directory

So do I need to perform both commands on the same session? something like:

```
session.getStdin().write("cd /root/somedir \n".getBytes());
session.getStdin().write("ls . ".getBytes());
```

Is that the correct way?? if so, why do we need `Session.execCommand`?

Comment: I have never used this specific library but did you try to obtain STDIN once, store it into variable and then use it?

Answer (score 1):

After doing some research, the only good solution I managed to find is calling the "cd" command within the same code as the "ls" command, like this

```
session.execCommand("cd /root/somedir ; ls .");
```

The semicolon will separate the two commands as in any bash code.

In this way,  you can query the session's result [`session.getExitStatus()`] of both the `cd` and `ls` commands, which is **much** better then writing the two commands to  `session.getStdIn()` (after writing to stdin, you kinda loose all the ability to check for exit status...)

Hope this will help the rest

Eyal

Answer (score 1):

According to the Ganymed FAQ (http://www.ganymed.ethz.ch/ssh2/FAQ.html), you are not allowed to send more than one command per Session object you generate. This is how SSH-2 apparently wants you to handle it. Your two options are to either combine the two commands like

```
session.execCommand("cd /root/somedir ; ls .");
```

However this wont always work and it get very ugly if you have more than a couple commands. The other way to do this is to open an interactive shell session and write the commands to standard in. This could look something like this:

```
Session sess = conn.openSession();
sess.requestDumbPTY();
sess.startShell();

OutputStream os = sess.getStdin();
os.write("cd /root/somedir\n".getBytes());
os.write("ls -1\n".getBytes());
os.write("exit\n".getBytes());

InputStream stdout = new StreamGobbler(sess.getStdout());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stdout));

//TODO
```

Note the use of the final exit command. Since this is being treated like a terminal window, if you do not exit from the program any loop you have reading the output of the server will never terminate because the server will be expecting more input

Comment: Thank you for this code! Helped solve something I've been stumped on for a while

Answer (score 0):

OK, I took a quick look on the Ganymed javadoc and although I did not try it myself I assume that you should use method `execCommand()` of session instead of writing into the STDIN. I am pretty sure that session is connected to remote shell and therefore handles the shell state including current directory, environment variables etc.

So, just do the following:

```
session.execCommand("cd /root/somedir \n".getBytes());
session.execCommand("ls . ".getBytes());
```

I hope this will work for you. Good luck.

Comment: Alex, I'm afraid there's no out-of-the-api-box solution for this question... I've been through the API back and forth for weeks... 
the code you suggested won't even compile, and after fixing it, will fail on the  the basic concepts of Ganymed SSH